# Espresso Record Test Doesn't provide code

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

I am new to espresso test, I tried to record test using espresso in my Android Studio (3.2), and it failed to produces recorded test. There's only created classes but no source code inside.
But when i try to use it on new project with sample navigation tab view, it works.

I already setup the the requirement from here, but nothing works

https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/setup

If anybody ever face the same issue, please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Are there any errors that are displayed?